# Jquery Script and ColdFusion

Tags: jquery, coldfusion

I have a JQuery script that I would like to integrate into my ColdFusion app that I found in one of the articles on this site. It is a simple script for inserting text at the cursor in a form field. It's must simpler than the JavaScript solutions that I've found.

```
jQuery("#btn").on('click', function() {
  var caretPos = document.getElementById("txt").selectionStart;
  var textAreaTxt = jQuery("#txt").val();
  var txtToAdd = "stuff";
  jQuery("#txt").val(textAreaTxt.substring(0, caretPos) + txtToAdd + textAreaTxt.substring(caretPos) );
});
```

The problem that I'm having is that ColdFusion sees the JQuery form names, #btn -or- #txt, as invalid constructs. I guess it is expecting a coldfusion variable there.

Is there anyway around this?

Comment: If at all possible, don't put JS code in your CFM files, instead put them in separate JS files. Then  you won't have this problem.

Comment: Or, you could simply remove the above JS from inside a `cfoutput` block

Answer (score 5):

Double the pound sign.
 `##btn` or `##txt`

Comment: Ok, so I've included the script in a separate js file define at the top of my page. It's definitely not within any cfoutput tags. Do I still need to double ##. Right now the script doesn't seem to be working and no errors in the console output in firebug.

Comment: If the JavasSript is in a separate .js file, and thus not processed by ColdFusion, you will no longer need double pound signs.

Comment: You could avoid the need for double `#` by not having the JS block you posted inside of a `cfoutput`.

Answer (score 0):

A good rule of thumb is to NOT include js in your cfm pages. Keep your concerns separate. Have your cfm page include your js file via `<script src=''>` tags.

Short of completely different files, keep all and any in-page js blocks in the cfml page outside of any `<cfoutput>` blocks and in their own  blocks clear up at the top (in the `<head>` is ideal) or clear at the bottom of your page.

Then the ColdFusion parser will not look at the `<script>` block at all and confuse pound-tags for the beginning of any ColdFusion variables or statements.

In the rare case you 'have to' (you never have to in my opinion - there is always a way not to do that) use js inside a `<cfoutput>` or other parsed cf block, you can double pound the identifiers (##).